# How to perform computations easily between every column in a polars DataFrame and the mean of that column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-polars, rust-polars, nodejs-polars

### Environment

```
macos:             monterey
node:              v18.1.0
nodejs-polars:     0.5.3
```

### Goal

Subtract every column in a [polars](https://www.pola.rs/) DataFrame with the mean of that column.

### Pandas solution

In pandas the solution is very concise thanks to `DataFrame.sub(other, axis='columns', level=None, fill_value=None)`. `other` is `scalar, sequence, Series, or DataFrame`:

```
df.sub(df.mean())
df - df.mean()
```

### nodejs-polars solution

While in nodejs-polars [function](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/51ef4ce1df73496ebfbc4b42594e29b99b27884b/nodejs-polars/polars/dataframe.ts), `other` only seems to be a `Series` according to `sub: (other) =>  wrap("sub", prepareOtherArg(other).inner())`.

#### 1. Prepare data

```
console.log(df)
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│   A     ┆   B     ┆   C     ┆   D     │
│ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     │
╞═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ 13520   ┆ -16     ┆ 384     ┆ 208     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 13472   ┆ -16     ┆ 384     ┆ 176     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 13456   ┆ -16     ┆ 368     ┆ 160     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 13472   ┆ -16     ┆ 368     ┆ 160     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 13472   ┆ -16     ┆ 352     ┆ 176     │
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

```
console.log(df.mean())
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│   A     ┆   B     ┆   C     ┆   D     │
│ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ f64     ┆ f64     ┆ f64     ┆ f64     │
╞═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ 13478.4 ┆ -16.0   ┆ 371.2   ┆ 176.0   │
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

#### 2. first try

```
df.sub(df.mean())

Error: Failed to determine supertype of Int64 and Struct([Field { name: "A", dtype: Int32 }, Field { name: "B", dtype: Int32 }, Field { name: "C", dtype: Int32 }, Field { name: "D", dtype: Int32 }])
```

#### 3. second try

```
df.sub(pl.Series(df.mean().row(0)))

Program crashes due to memory problems.
```

#### 4. third try

After some investigations, I noticed the [tests](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/eb42b99d82ed2a64e2817381b54491e0cb0fcf3b/nodejs-polars/__tests__/dataframe.test.ts):

```
test("sub", () => {
  const actual = pl.DataFrame({
    "foo": [1, 2, 3],
    "bar": [4, 5, 6]
  }).sub(1);
  const expected = pl.DataFrame({
    "foo": [0, 1, 2],
    "bar": [3, 4, 5]
  });
  expect(actual).toFrameEqual(expected);
});
test("sub:series", () => {
  const actual = pl.DataFrame({
    "foo": [1, 2, 3],
    "bar": [4, 5, 6]
  }).sub(pl.Series([1, 2, 3]));
  const expected = pl.DataFrame({
    "foo": [0, 0, 0],
    "bar": [3, 3, 3]
  });
  expect(actual).toFrameEqual(expected);
});
```

nodejs-polars seems to be unable to complete this task gracefully right now. So my current solution is a bit cumbersome: perform operations column by column then concat the results.

```
pl.concat(df.columns.map((col) => df.select(col).sub(df.select(col).mean(0).toSeries())), {how:'horizontal'})
```

Is there a better or easier way to do it?

#### 5. new try

I just came out an easier solution, but it's hard to understand, and I'm still trying to figure out what happened under the hood.

```
df.select(pl.col('*').sub(pl.col('*').mean()))
```

Answer (score 8):

You tagged this problem with [python-polars], so I'll provide a solution using Polars with Python.  (Perhaps you can translate that to Node-JS.)

Starting with our data:

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": [13520, 13472, 13456, 13472, 13472],
        "B": [-16, -16, -16, -16, -16],
        "C": [384, 384, 368, 368, 352],
        "D": [208, 176, 160, 160, 176],
    }
)
df
```

```
shape: (5, 4)
┌───────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ A     ┆ B   ┆ C   ┆ D   │
│ ---   ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64   ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═══════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 13520 ┆ -16 ┆ 384 ┆ 208 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 13472 ┆ -16 ┆ 384 ┆ 176 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 13456 ┆ -16 ┆ 368 ┆ 160 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 13472 ┆ -16 ┆ 368 ┆ 160 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 13472 ┆ -16 ┆ 352 ┆ 176 │
└───────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

We can very concisely solve this problem:

```py
df.with_columns([
    (pl.all() - pl.all().mean()).suffix('_centered')
])
```

```
shape: (5, 8)
┌───────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┐
│ A     ┆ B   ┆ C   ┆ D   ┆ A_centered ┆ B_centered ┆ C_centered ┆ D_centered │
│ ---   ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---        │
│ i64   ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ f64        ┆ f64        ┆ f64        ┆ f64        │
╞═══════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪════════════╡
│ 13520 ┆ -16 ┆ 384 ┆ 208 ┆ 41.6       ┆ 0.0        ┆ 12.8       ┆ 32.0       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 13472 ┆ -16 ┆ 384 ┆ 176 ┆ -6.4       ┆ 0.0        ┆ 12.8       ┆ 0.0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 13456 ┆ -16 ┆ 368 ┆ 160 ┆ -22.4      ┆ 0.0        ┆ -3.2       ┆ -16.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 13472 ┆ -16 ┆ 368 ┆ 160 ┆ -6.4       ┆ 0.0        ┆ -3.2       ┆ -16.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 13472 ┆ -16 ┆ 352 ┆ 176 ┆ -6.4       ┆ 0.0        ┆ -19.2      ┆ 0.0        │
└───────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┘
```

If you want to overwrite the columns, you can eliminate the `suffix` expression:

```py
df.with_columns([
    (pl.all() - pl.all().mean())
])
```

```
shape: (5, 4)
┌───────┬─────┬───────┬───────┐
│ A     ┆ B   ┆ C     ┆ D     │
│ ---   ┆ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ f64   ┆ f64 ┆ f64   ┆ f64   │
╞═══════╪═════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ 41.6  ┆ 0.0 ┆ 12.8  ┆ 32.0  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -6.4  ┆ 0.0 ┆ 12.8  ┆ 0.0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -22.4 ┆ 0.0 ┆ -3.2  ┆ -16.0 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -6.4  ┆ 0.0 ┆ -3.2  ┆ -16.0 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ -6.4  ┆ 0.0 ┆ -19.2 ┆ 0.0   │
└───────┴─────┴───────┴───────┘
```

**Edit**: essentially, the `polars.all` or the `polars.col('*')` replicates an entire expression for each column, so that:

```py
pl.col('*') - pl.col('*').mean()
```

is syntactic sugar for:

```py
[
  pl.col('A') - pl.col('A').mean(),
  pl.col('B') - pl.col('B').mean(),
  pl.col('C') - pl.col('C').mean(),
  pl.col('D') - pl.col('D').mean(),
]
```

Comment: Awesome! thank you very much, translated: `df.withColumns(pl.col('*').sub(pl.col('*').mean()))` or `df.select(pl.col('*').sub(pl.col('*').mean()))`

Comment: I provided some further explanation in an edit.